# API Gateway Micro Service Lookup Method

Tags: aggregate, microservices, api-design, api-gateway

I have built an API, with an API Gateway and two micro services.
The two micro services are Products and Categories.

The API call can do the following:

```
/v1/account/getAccount          // gets all accounts
/v1/account/getAccount/44       // gets account 44
/v1/categories/getCategory      // gets all categories
/v1/categories/getCategory/24   // gets category 24
```

Accounts can be in categories. What's the best way to go about getting all accounts with their corresponding categories.

1. The account micro service makes a call to the category micro service
2. The gateway makes a synchronous call to the account micro service, then loops through these accounts to make a call to the category micro service to get each corresponding category
3. Put point 2 into a new Aggregating micro service
4. Some other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: 4 - Some other way.

The problem you're having is a direct consequence of how you designed your microservices. Usually (this depends on the use-case of course), it is a *bad idea* to have services be "CRUD" services for different entities, without any business logic.

Why is this a bad idea? For the same reasons it is a bad idea to do the same in a monolith. It creates dependencies, makes the microservices depend on each other, ultimately resulting in a solution that has the worst of both worlds (microservices and monoliths).

This is further reinforced by your requirements to get all customers with all categories. If you design your services the right way, you would not need to extract the full dataset from them.

**The right way to do it**: Design your services around business functions, instead of data. If both customer and category are need for a function, then those should be actually together and form a "microservice" with the appropriate function (you didn't actually mention any).

Try to separate different aspects of data to form different functions, even if it means some data may be redundant.

Comment: Interesting. So I have a category browser, and a product browser. Product browser can show categories it's in, but category browser wouldn't show products. So you're saying this should be two different micro services, where the product browser would also get categories from the database using a lookup?

Comment: Well, if you "just" want to show stuff, why do you need a HTTP API? Why not just render HTML? What I mean is, do things for a reason. If there is no reason to separate things, then don't. If there is no reason to have a HTTP API, then don't. Your problem goes away, if you just put the two together, as far as I understand.